# Could not find function

Tags: r

In have code that looks like this (trying to filter a few variables).

```
library(magrittr)

d.cty <- filter(ann2012full, agglvl_code==70)%.%
select(state, county, abb, avg_annual_pay, annual_avg_emplvl)%.%
mutate(wage=Discretize(avg_annual_pay),
empquantile=Discretize(annual_avg_emplvl))
```

dataset

```
head(ann2012full)
 [1] area_fips                        own_code                         industry_code                   
 [4] agglvl_code                      size_code                        year                            
 [7] qtr                              disclosure_code                  annual_avg_estabs               
[10] annual_avg_emplvl                total_annual_wages               taxable_annual_wages            
[13] annual_contributions             annual_avg_wkly_wage             avg_annual_pay                  
[16] lq_disclosure_code               lq_annual_avg_estabs             lq_annual_avg_emplvl            
[19] lq_total_annual_wages            lq_taxable_annual_wages          lq_annual_contributions         
[22] lq_annual_avg_wkly_wage          lq_avg_annual_pay                oty_disclosure_code             
[25] oty_annual_avg_estabs_chg        oty_annual_avg_estabs_pct_chg    oty_annual_avg_emplvl_chg       
[28] oty_annual_avg_emplvl_pct_chg    oty_total_annual_wages_chg       oty_total_annual_wages_pct_chg  
[31] oty_taxable_annual_wages_chg     oty_taxable_annual_wages_pct_chg oty_annual_contributions_chg    
[34] oty_annual_contributions_pct_chg oty_annual_avg_wkly_wage_chg     oty_annual_avg_wkly_wage_pct_chg
[37] oty_avg_annual_pay_chg           oty_avg_annual_pay_pct_chg       agglvl_title                    
[40] industry_title                   own_title                        size_title                      
[43] state_fips                       area_title                       polyname                        
[46] county                           abb                              state                           
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

I think the field names are fine, and I think the data overall is fine, so I'm not sure what's going on here.  I'm probably just missing something simple, but I can't see it.  Anyone have any insight into what's going on here?  Thanks.

Comment: Could not find *which* function?

Comment: This looks like an old dplyr code. Where did you get it from? You need to `library(dplyr)` and replace all the `%.%` with `%>%`

Comment: This looks right David.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: If you have some idea about the time that the code was developed/written you can use the "checkpoint" package. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/checkpoint/index.html